# Structuring button click methods to avoid code repetition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following two button click methods that create an array from three TextBoxes, order the values, insert them into a database and then select the values in the same order. The only difference between the two buttons is that one orders the values in ascending order and the other in descending order.

I'm not used to working with C#. Can anybody suggest the best way to structure my code so I'm not repeating it for each button? Normally I'd write a function and have each button pass it arguments. Is that the right way to go here?

Thanks in advance.

**Button1**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
    var orderedlist = list.OrderBy(x => (x)).ToArray();
```

...

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from lists order by values asc", conn);
```

**Button2**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
    var orderedlist = list.OrderByDescending(x => (x)).ToArray();
```

...

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from lists order by values desc", conn);
```

Comment: Use a function, call it from both buttons with different arguments.

Comment: Maybe provide a little more code or an explanation of what the buttons are doing? From what you've provided I'd think a function call with arguments would be best but there may be other (better) options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just assign both `Button` click events to the same handler and use the `sender` choose what sorting you want.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
    var orderedlist = (sender as Button).AccessKey  == "Button1" // or whatever name it is
                      ? list.OrderByDescending(x => (x)).ToArray()
                      : list.OrderBy(x => (x)).ToArray();

    .............
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. :) The only problem now is "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: perhaps `AccessKey` will work instaed of Name, or whatever property is unique between the 2 buttons

Answer (score 2):

On option would be to create a function, sort:

```
public list sort(String order)
{
     var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
     var orderedlist = list.OrderByDescending(x => (x)).ToArray();
     ...

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from lists order by values " + order, conn)
     ...
     return SortedList;
}
```

Call sort("asc") to create the sorted list in ascending order, and sort("desc") to sort in descending order. And no code repetition :)

Answer (score 0):

You could basically use functional programming here. Abstract the part of the code that changes into a function.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperFunction(list => list.OrderBy(x => x));
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperFunction(list => list.OrderByDescending(x => x));
}

private void HelperFunction(Func<IEnumerable<string>, <IEnumerable<string>> listOrderer)
{
    var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };

    var orderedList = listOrderer(list).ToArray();

    // rest of code
}
```